# SCSS/SASS list reverse iteration (backward loop)

Tags: sass

Reversing the order of a `@for` iteration output in SCSS can be done as so:

### SCSS example: [GIST DEMO](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d810a109d2542d43b2067c9309682a70)

```
$colors : green, gold, red;

a{
  $i : length($colors);
  @each $c in $colors {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}){
           fill:$c;
      }
      $i : $i - 1;
  }
}
```

### Output:

```
a:nth-child(3) {
  fill: green;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
  fill: gold;
}
a:nth-child(1) {
  fill: red;
}
```

---

## Is this the best way of SASS reverse iterating?

Does anyone know of a more "SCSS native" way of achieving this goal which increases readability?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is ok.

You can create a function that will [reverse](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/#reverse-a-list) your array:

```
@function reverse($list, $recursive: false) {
   $result: ();

   @for $i from length($list)*-1 through -1 {
      @if type-of(nth($list, abs($i))) == list and $recursive {
        $result: append($result, reverse(nth($list, abs($i)), $recursive));      
      }

      @else {
        $result: append($result, nth($list, abs($i)));
      }
   }

   @return $result;
}

$list: #aaa, #bbb, #ccc, #ddd;
$new-list: reverse($list);

@for $i from 1 through length($new-list){
  div:nth-child(#{$i}){
    color: nth($new-list, $i);
  }
}
```

You can use `nth-last-child` selector.

```
@for $i from 1 through length($list){
  div:nth-last-child(#{$i}){
    color: nth($list, $i);
  }
}
```

You can rewrite your array: `$list: #ddd, #aaa, #bbb, #ccc` and use `nth-child`.